# getting integer value entered from dynamically created edittext in a dialog in Android throws NumberFormatException

Tags: android, dynamic, android-edittext, numberformatexception

I'm new, so sorry if this turns out so simple that I should have solved myself. I've spent a couple days thinking about it. I've researched a ton and searched many other posts here, but no success.

I have a dialog with DatePicker, Buttons, EditText fields, and Spinners. I can populate everything i need from the stored items in my DB to the dialog. But when i try to get the numbers entered into some of the EditText fields, it throws NumberFormatException. I can hard code values into variables to store, and hide my attempt to get the value in a try and it will run fine. The values get stored and when I open the dialog again they populate into the right areas.

Here's partial code-

```
        EditText et = new EditText(getContext()); 
        for(int i=0; i<=etcount; i++){
        placed = -1; //reset for next iteration

        //try to get number from edittext
        et.findViewById(i);
        placed = Integer.parseInt(et.getText().toString());

        awake++;
        /*
        try {
            //et.findViewById(i);
            placed = Integer.parseInt(findViewById(i).toString());
            //placed = Integer.parseInt(et.getText().toString());
        } catch(NumberFormatException nfe) {
           System.out.println("Could not parse " + nfe);
        }*/
```

I commented out the try block cause I wanted to troubleshoot quickly.

etcount variable is initialized at onCreate with -1 value, before getting values from DB. If there are values stored in the DB it gets incremented by 1, then code is called to dynamically add an EditText and Spinner to the layout. Also the EditText id is set to the value of etcount. Here is that code-

```
//this will be ran when +placement button pressed, or if there are items in db stored
//adds 2 rows to dialog, one for textview to label items, one row for edittext with number
//and spinner with what item it is
private void createTableRow(int numPlaced, int itmPlaced){ 


    etcount++; //used to count how many edittext fields there are so that they can be saved later
    spincount++; //to count how many spinner there are


    tl = (TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.tableLayoutVisit); //the tablelayout name
    //need to create row for textview, then another row for edittext and spinner
    tr1 = new TableRow(this.getContext()); //table row 1, for textview
    tr1.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
            LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    TextView tv = new TextView(this.getContext());
    tv.setText("Amount Placed");
    tv.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
            LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

    tr1.addView(tv); //add textview to tablerow1
    tl.addView(tr1, new TableLayout.LayoutParams( //add row to tablelayout
            LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));


    tr2 = new TableRow(this.getContext()); //tablerow2: edittext and spinner
    tr2.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
            LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));        
    EditText et = new EditText(this.getContext());
    et.setId(etcount);
    et.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
    if(numPlaced!=0){ //if being populated from previous visit  
        et.setText(Integer.toString(numPlaced));
        //et.setText("" +numPlaced);
    }

    //need to have listener to read data
    et.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
            LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));


    Spinner spin = new Spinner(this.getContext());
    spin.setId(spincount);
    spinArray = getContext().getResources().getStringArray(R.array.itemplaced);
    ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(getContext(),
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, spinArray);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);


    spin.setAdapter(adapter);
    if(itmPlaced!=-1){
        spin.setSelection(itmPlaced); //assign correct value 
    }
    spin.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
            LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    tr2.addView(et);
    tr2.addView(spin);


    tl.addView(tr2, new TableLayout.LayoutParams( //add row to tablelayout
            LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

}
```

I pass it (0,-1) if it is a new item and not currently stored in DB. Also you probably noticed I forced it to accept TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER. But I don't think the issue is there. Again, if I hard code values it will save into the DB and the next time I open it it dynamically creates EditText/Spinner row in layout and populates the EditText with the value in the DB.

So... something is wrong with the first section I think, the et.findViewById(i); or placed = Integer.parseInt(et.getText().toString());. The value of "etcount" should be -1 if nothing was populated from DB, and 0 etc(etcount++) each time something is populated from DB.

Sorry if this is longwinded, wanted to be specific. Hope this is enough info! Any help would be great!!! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
    EditText et = new EditText(this);

    for (int i = 0; i <= etcount; i++) {
        placed = -1;
        et = (EditText) this.findViewById(i);
        placed = Integer.parseInt(et.getText().toString());
        //...
    }
```

It seems to me that I've found an error.
The main problem in your code that you do not assign unique values in setId methods. In your case some editTexts and spins can have the same IDs. This is wrong. Every element must have a unique identifier. This is the first what you should correct in your code.

After that you can use my approach. But it seems to me that something wrong in this approach. It is not beautiful ) Try to find best practices in this field.

Comment: Thanks Yury! So i changed those things but no dice... still same. I'm wondering if the "EditText et = new EditText(this.getContext());" and "et.setId(etcount);" code when the row is created is actually assigning a unique id to each EditText that is created. It doesn't seem to be null.. but maybe it's pulling some other resource and not finding the right EditText? Maybe I should save each EditText that is created to another variable, some array type resource? I might try that when I get home from work!! Thanks for the tips!!

Comment: See my comments in my answer.

Comment: Thanks Yury!! Sorry not sure how I missed that... But they do have unique ids, the spin is set in onCreate to 99, the edittext is -1. At the first edittext and spinner addition they are incremented to 100 and 0 respectively... Does that make sense?

Comment: I think yes. In any case provide us with your findings and if you still need our help.

Comment: Ok!! It is working now. I used the etcount to give unique id to EditText's like my above code, and incremented it each time. I spent more time debugging and your code above worked! Casting EditText found the correct EditText and the parseInt code worked. I was running into a different error when I used your code though because of different variable assignment, but that was separate issue in different area of code, so I thought your answer didn't work, sorry... The problem was getting the right EditText and getting the value. Thanks!!! I'll mark this answered since your answer works!

Answer (score 0):

Few suggestions from my side: 
1)  try to check whether getText method not giving you empty string"" or null.
2)  place your  EditText et; to class variable not a local instance.
example  public class ExampleActivity extends Activity
{
 EditText et;//place it here instead in oncreate methods.

}// or make it final if defining in oncreate.

according to your code, issues seems in your for loop
        for(int i=0; i<=etcount; i++){
        placed = -1; //reset for next iteration

```
    //try to get number from edittext  // which edit text you are trying to access. am sure it is  returning null to you.
    et.findViewById(i);
    placed = Integer.parseInt(et.getText().toString());
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the response!! I moved the EditText declaration to a class variable, just inside the class before the onCreate or other methods. But it seems to respond the same way. I also tried adding et.getText().toString()!=null and et.getText()!=null as well as both of those with with "" instead of null, and incremented a variable inside an IF statement based on the result, and it does increment. So et.getText() doesn't seem to be returning null...

Comment: et.findViewById(i); // this line fetching the view but not assigning into et.



  make it et = et.findViewById(i);